# Sencha extJS google map marker does not click

Tags: extjs, google-maps-markers, extjs6

I created  a marker with the following line

```
var m = new google.maps.Marker({
```

and then I added a listener  with the following lines

```
m.addListener('click', function(e) {
                    markerClick(e);
             });
```

but I am taking the following error

Uncaught ReferenceError: markerClick is not defined

but I don't know how to call the markerClick function 
below  I am  sending you the code

https://gist.github.com/YannisKalaijakis/3545eabe2ffc7bfdb07cacfafcb1857c

Comment: Move markerClick to MapController's body and call it anywhere you need with this.markerClick

Answer (score 0):

As i can this on you'r code the `markerClick` function was a event of map cmp.

So into you'r addListener function callback you can't only call `markerClick(e)`.

You have to fire a event to the map cmp.

Can you give me the scope into you'r listener callback please ?

Without further detail I would say `this.markerClick(e)` or `this.fireEvent('markerClick', this, e)`

Comment: well the markerClick is defined in this scope
 config: {
         listen: {
             component: {
                 'map': {
                     markerClick: function (marker) {
while the listener is in  the initMarker as you can see in gist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining markerClick as a MapController function?

```
    Ext.define('Wp.view.map.MapController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.map',
    requires: [
        'Ext.container.Container',
        'Ext.layout.container.Border',
        'Ext.ux.GMapPanel',
        'Ext.ux.IFrame',
        'Ext.window.Window'
    ],
    config: {
        listen: {
            // The fireEvent() is coming from a component so we listen on the component event domain
            component: {
                // The component we are listening to is alias : map
                'map': {
                    // The fireEvent() from the map component
                    markerClick: this.markerClick
                }
            }
        }
    },

    markerClick: function (marker) {
       // your code...
    },

    initMarker: function () {
        debugger;
        var me = this,
                map = me.getView(), //Reference to map view
                store = map.getViewModel().getStore('Markers'), // Get the store from the ViewModel
                data;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: {
                lat: 31,
                lng: 31
            },
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            zoomControl: true
        });

        store.load(function (records) {
            Ext.each(records, function (record) {
                // more code...
                m.addListener('click', function (e) {
                    this.markerClick(e);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```